# Индекс минимального числа

Tags: python, массивы

Есть список `x = [5, 7, 6, 8, 0, 5]`
Как сделать чтобы выводился индекс минимального числа, то есть 5?

Нужно чтобы функция работала с любым списком.

Comment: Линейный поиск с запоминанием индекса

Comment: в вашем примере индекс минимального числа равен 4, а не 5

Comment: уточните вопрос пожалуйста - функция должна возвращать индекс первого встреченного минимального элемента или всех минимумов?

Answer (score 5):

```
def f(lst):
    minimal = min(lst)
    index = []
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        if lst[i] == minimal:
            index.append(i)
    return index
```

Comment: 1). автор вопроса просил функцию. 2). что, если минимальное число в списке будет встречаться несколько раз?

Comment: @strawdog, по поводу второго вопроса - это надо адресовать автору топика)

Answer (score 4):

```
x = [5, 7, 6, 8, 0, 5]
x.index(min(x))
```

Результат

> Out[8]: 4

(и это правильно, а не 5, как вы указали).

Answer (score 1):

```
def minimum_indices(array):
    min_array = min(array)
    return [index for index, elem in enumerate(A) if elem == min_A]

A = [5, 7, 6, 8, 0, 5, 0];
print(min_indexies(A)) # 4, 6
```